# how to use active support core ext date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activesupport

What is `active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations` for? There are `/date`, `/time`, and `/date_time` for `Date`, `Time` and `DateTime`, respectively. But what is `/date_and_time` for?

I tried to require it instead of `date_time`, then I got NoMethodError for the methods defined in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those modules `date_and_time` are there because they are modules that are included by all of the `Date`, `Time` and `DateTime` core extensions. Those modules extend those classes with the same methods. Hence they are grouped under Date *and* Time, because you get the same new methods across all classes.

So, they are modules, meant to be included as extensions. You cannot require them separately and expect new functionality, unless you are meaning to use them to extend class functionality through `include`.

Here's an example directly from the Rails source on how it's used (taken from `core_ext/date/calculations` in this case):

```
require "active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations"

class Date
  include DateAndTime::Calculations
  ...
end
```

You can [look at the source yourself](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/87d9228d9d2225296f68795ef685f617a844f4df/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext), or [check out the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html) for the added methods.

For example, with that extension in both `Date` and `Time`, you can now do:

```
Time.now.last_year
Date.today.last_year
```

Same method is available, for both classes.